# How to calculate the norm?

Tags: normed-spaces

We have the vector :
$$
w=(1,3,5,1,3,5,\ldots,1,3) \in \mathbb{R}^{3k-1},
$$
and we want to calculate its norm $\|w\|$.

Now I would like to know how the norm $\|w\|$ can be calculated.

Comment: There are many norms on $\mathbb{R}^{3k-1}$; which are you trying to calculate? In any case, it should help to note that there are $k$ entries which are $1$s, $k$ entries which are $3$s, and $k-1$ entries which are $5$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tuple is in $\mathbb{R}^{3k-1}$ then there must be $(k-1)$ occurrences of $1$, $3$, and $5$ with one additional occurrence for $1$ and $3$ (judging by the tail of the vector representing $w$). So:

$\|w\|=\sqrt{k+9k+25(k-1)}=\sqrt{35k-25}$

Answer (score 1):

Well you could put many different norms on $\mathbb{R}^{3k-1}$, but if you are using the standard one, the norm of a vector is just the square root of the sum of the squares of its components, i.e.
\begin{equation}
||w||=\sqrt{1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots}
\end{equation}